# Excel Summing over Rows with for loop - Type mismatch error

Tags: vba, excel, confidence-interval

so I am currently working on an Excel sheet where I have to calculate confidence intervals. Long story short, I think the only way I can do this automatically, is to write vba code. The first step would be to calculate the average of the cells in a column for several columns in the sheet. What I did:

```
Dim temp As Double
temp = 0

Dim it_row As Long
for it_row = 1 to 100
     if IsBlank(Sheet.Cells(it_row,it_col)) then
          temp = temp + 0
     else
          temp = temp + Sheet.Cells(it_row,it_col).Value
     end if
next it_row

Dim Average As Double
Average = temp/100
'writing average in another cell
```

This code does not work, as the compiler returns Type missmatch, error code 13
in the line

`temp = temp + Sheet.Cells(it_row,it_col).Value`

I tried to do a `CDouble(Sheet.Cells(it_row,it_col).Value)` but that did not work.

Any help is appreciated, as I am quite desperate because googling did not really help me.

I should mention that I do have to use vba and this code because this is part of a bigger automated process and my supervisor said I must use vba for automation in the next step.

Comment: then `Sheet.Cells(it_row,it_col).Value` has text or an error in it.  You will need to test whether the cell is a number before trying to add it to `temp`

Comment: Also I do not see where you declare and assign a value to `it_col`

Comment: if your cells have formulas that return `""`, then `ISBLANK` will return false.  Maybe try `Sheet.Cells(it_row,it_col) = ""` instead.

Comment: ´it_col` is an iterator that is used in a do loop that checks whether a cell in the first row that declares the name of a column is empty or not. so in fact i do have two loops. one iterating over columns then iterating over rows

Comment: I find it unlikely that you have a worksheet with the **codename** *sheet*.

Comment: @ScottCraner `Sheet.Cells(it_row,it_col) = ""` does not change the type missmatch. How would I test whether the cell has text or an error as value? Cause I would have to change the value to 0 if thats the case, wouldnt I?

Comment: @Jeeped I defined it like that. `Dim Sheet As Worksheet _ Set Sheet = Excel.ActiveWorksheet` if that is not okay please tell me, as I said I am really new to vba

Comment: 1. It is `CDbl` not `CDouble`. 2. What is the value of `Sheet.Cells(it_row,it_col).Value` on the fail? Is it text or possibly even text-that-looks-like-a-number?

Comment: Have you tried--> If IsNumeric(Sheet.Cells(it_row, it_col).Value) Then
    temp = temp + Sheet.Cells(it_row, it_col).Value
End If

Comment: Should be easier with Excel Formulas. There is even a CONFIDENCE function https://support.office.com/en-us/article/CONFIDENCE-function-75ccc007-f77c-4343-bc14-673642091ad6

Answer (score 0):

The [Average](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836809.aspx) and Sum Excel Functions ignore text, boolean, and empty values:

```
Average = Application.Average(Sheet.Cells(1, it_col).Resize(100))
```

Answer (score -2):

Check

```
Sheet.Cells(it_row,it_col).Value
```

...with

```
if isnumeric(Sheet.Cells(it_row,it_col).Value)
```

...before adding it to a double type value. If that check fails, then you can chose to skip it or treat it as sth. else.
I would've added this as a comment, but I don't have enough rep. to add comments.

Comment: This comment has already been made.  please do not use the answer space for comments, it is a good way to lose the rep your already have.